# How to work with Webbrowser.Document property when the content is XPS?

Tags: vba, webbrowser-control, domdocument, xps

I'm using a native, non-.NET WebBrowser control to display either an HTML page or an XPS document to the user. I would simply `Navigate` to either.

I'm happy with the HTML part, but the XPS document normally doesn't fit the browser bounds. I want to fit it by width. This happens if I double click the contents, but I want to do it programmatically upon document load.

It is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752052%28v=vs.85%29) that `WebBrowser.Document` returns an `IDispatch` for the hosted document. Naturally, I want to obtain this property and do something like `Webbrowser1.Document.Parent.FitToWidth()`.

The problem is that I can't figure what methods the returned `IDispatch` actually has and how to work with it.
I tried to fetch the class/interface information with `TypeLib Info`, no luck, the object doesn't support that.
I tried some common properties, such as `Name` or `Parent`, they don't seem to be present either.
I assumed it could be something similar to `DocumentViewer`, but again, "Object does not support this action."

**So how do I use the Webbrowser.Document property when the content is XPS?**

*(BTW, the error is strange. In the VBA world, it sould be "Object doesn't support this property or method," but it's in fact "Object does not support this action." Is it the webbrowser that prevents me from even using the document (because it's, say, not safe for scripting)?)*

Would like to avoid simulating a double click within the browser bounds.

Comment: I suspect what's happening is the WebBrowser control is hosting the xpsviewer browser plugin, rather than natively displaying the xps.

Comment: @Jon Does that leave a chance of sending a command to that browser?

Comment: It may be possible if you can find an api reference for the plugin, but it would be brittle and probably start failing on newer versions of windows. Being able to view XPS documents directly in IE was a temporary fix - I don't think the plugin is being distributed on newer installs.

Answer (score 0):

@GSery have you tried getting the pDisp from the events such as BeforeNavigate2 and DocumentComplete so that you can play around with the pDisp (and other arguments passed in by the event) to see what else you can do with it?

Of course, the WBControl.Document provides .Width and .Height properties, I'm sure you've tried these, if you haven't, give them a go. The other alternative is running javascript in the document window. Like this (WB is ur WebBrowser control name), sScript is you're javascript file to alter window.height & window.width, each new line of js code can be seperates by ; and one line can contain many lines seperated by ;. Also, the sLanguage must be set equals to "JScript" and you are ready to go.

```
WB.Document.parentWindow.execScript sScript, sLanguage
```

Otherwise, we can use another trick, load the .XPS in an iframe inside a main/parent document, and set the width of the iframe in the HTML hosted by the parent/main document. This should force the XPS to behave, and of course, you can run the .execScript (javascript lines od code) on your main / parent document as well (and access your frames from there).

Also, if you are using a .NET version os the WB control, you are welcome to use .InvokeScript in place of .execScript (but both should work).

Also, when resolving parent/frame window heirarchy, you can do so under WB.Document.parentWindow or instead within the JavaScript you are executing, or you can mix and match and resolve document hierarchy using both you exe application code and your javascript code.

Let me knwo how you get along and if there is anything I can do to help.

Comment: Sorry, but none of this makes sense. XPS document is displayed by an XPS viewer which gets loaded inside webbrowser *instead* of an HTML document. There is no parent document, no HTML DOM model, no iframes, nowhere to execute a script, and .width and .height properties are useless because they are always equal to the control's size. Even if there was a place to execute a script at, my question is exactly about what methods the hosted XPS viewer has. I don't know their names so I can't call them, from a script or from something else.

Comment: @GSerg I understand what you are saying, but one of the suggestions I made was if you created a parent HTML documnt, included an iframe tag inside with its src attribute pointing to your XPS document, I get the feeling that the XPS document will load inside the HTML parent document, and you'll be able to execute scripts from the parent HTML document, including changing the iframes width, or even just setting the iframes width when you are composing the iframe html tag. I'm thinking there's a realistic chance of that working, as the XPS viewer is unlikely to try & hijack the entire parent HTML.